# send image file to a php file via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to this.All i am trying to do is upload a image and send it to server to insert in a  database.As a start i am limited to echoing the file name which i will send.But i kept on failing to do so.Getting some noisy or undesirable output which makes no sence.Can't figure out the mistakes in this code.It would be great if someone help me with this problem.Thanks!

html and ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>file upload</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->

        <style>
            #mydiv{
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                width:80px;
                height:30px;
                background:crimson;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                padding:auto;
                border-radius:4px ;
                border:1px solid black;
                font-size:22px;
            }
            #files{
                   position: absolute;
                   top: 0;
                   right: 0;
                   margin: 0;
                   padding: 0;
                   font-size: 20px;
                   cursor: pointer;
                   opacity: 0;
                   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='file.php'  id='myform' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' style='width:80px;height:70px;border:2px solid skyblue;'>
      <div id='mydiv'>upload
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />

      </div>
      <span id='txtHint'></span>
    </form>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {


      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      formData.append('image_name',f,f.name);

              var name =f.name;
              console.log(name);
        if (name='') {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML ='fill the name field';
            return;
        } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("POST", "file2.php", true)
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        xmlhttp.send(formData);

        }

      }

    }

 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
echo $_FILES['image_name'];
```

Comment: try to `echo $_FILES['image_name']['name']`

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump ($_FILES);` in the php?

Comment: it gives me some noisy output.See the first comment below ,you will get an idea

Comment: @AL-zami it looks like the answer below was only echoing out a particular part of `$_FILES`. Not only that, the error you're getting when you try echoing out $_FILES['image_name'] is saying that the php file is not receiving the file at all. Simply using `var_dump($_FILES,$_REQUEST);` will let you see everything and anything that was passed to your php script

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the upload file name just do:

```
echo $_FILES['image_name']['name']
```

EDIT : According to the name of your html input

```
echo $_FILES['files']['name']
```

Comment: it returns this : (no idea what it is) Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Undefined index: image_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\file2.php on line 3

Comment: i see try this instead `echo $_FILES['files']['name']`

Comment: returns the same.I already told in the question section that i am new to this kind of stuff.Do this,do that not going to help the cause.it would be better if you can explain something about the problem

Comment: i would to but i really don't know what you try to accomplish. I just provide in code above the way to return the name of uploaded file from server

Comment: i can suggest to use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload . I know it doesn't answer to your question but it could help

Answer (score -1):

What about to use BlueImp ? BlueImp is the best i think, and you can easily include on your projects

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: This answer dosn't add any information on the actual the problem with the above code